Inverse of a banded bisymmetric matrix
I have a banded bisymmetric matrix, say
$ A = \begin{pmatrix}
a & d & f & 0 & 0 \\
d & b & e & g & 0 \\
f & e & c & e & f \\
0 & g & e & b & d \\
0 & 0 & f & d & a 
\end{pmatrix}  $,
not necessarily a tridiagonal 5x5 matrix, but a general bisymmetric NxN with band K.
While I know that the inverse of a band-limited matrix is not necessarily banded, can we say something if we have the above symmetry in addition ? Like, is it banded and, if so, what is the length of band ?
If the inverse is still not necessarily band-limited, is there any additional property that could help ?

A single randomly-generated example in MATLAB shows that this extra symmetry does not ensure that the inverse of a banded matrix is banded.

$\pmatrix{2&1&0\cr1&3&1\cr0&1&4\cr}^{-1}=(1/18)\pmatrix{11&-4&1\cr-4&8&-2\cr1&-2&5\cr}$

It seems that your example is a symmetric matrix, not a bisymmetric matrix. @GerryMyerson

@user3, thanks, I missed that. But just change that $4$ to a $2$: $$\pmatrix{2&1&0\cr1&3&1\cr0&1&2}^{-1}=(1/8)\pmatrix{5&-2&1\cr-2&4&-2\cr1&-2&5\cr}$$
